# Can request only one set of permissions at a time. Trying to access my android Camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm trying to get access to my camera and what happened is that it does not open the camera and kept says that "Can request only one set of permissions at a time". So anybody can help with this problem?

I got this message on my logcat:

> I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:318319760
>   intent:Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS
>   pkg=com.google.android.packageinstaller (has extras) } W/Activity: Can
>   request only one set of permissions at a time

And here is my code that I've referred for requesting the permission on camera:

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 42;
    private static final int PERMISSION_COUNT = 1;    
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private boolean arePermissionDenied(){
        for(int i = 0; i<PERMISSION_COUNT;i++){
            if(checkSelfPermission(PERMISSIONS[i])!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);

        if(requestCode==REQUEST_PERMISSIONS && grantResults.length > 0){
            if(arePermissionDenied()){
                ((ActivityManager)(this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE))).clearApplicationUserData();
                recreate();
            }
            else{
                onResume();
            }
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    //Variable onResume method
    private boolean isCameraInitialized;
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private static SurfaceHolder myHolder;
    private static CameraPreview mPreview;
    private static OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = null;

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS,REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }

        if(!isCameraInitialized){
            mCamera=Camera.open();
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this,mCamera);
            frameLayout.addView(mPreview);
            rotateCamera();
            orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this) {
                @Override
                public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                    rotateCamera();
                }
            };
            orientationEventListener.enable();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code. Firstly use something like this to check if the user has granted permission instead of your `arePermissionDenied` method:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
```

Then, you could request users to grant permission as follows:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, requestCode);
```

After clicking request we can get result in you `onRequestPermissionResult` method as demonstrated below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!!